# Print out vector of strings backwards

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program that takes in user input, store it into a vector of strings, and prints out the vector according to the functions.

for this function, "display_backwards", it is supposed to display the input of the user in a mirrored-like image.

I'm having trouble writing the code and it's giving me errors which I don't understand why

This is my code:

```
void asci_art::display_backwards(vector<string> art)
{
char swap[100];
cout << "Your Artwork in mirrored image" << endl;
cout    << "=============================" <<endl;

for (unsigned int i=0; i < art.size(); i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j < art[i].size(); j++)
    {

        swap[j] = art[i].end()-j;
        art[i].begin()+j = swap[j];
    }
}

for(int k= 0; k < swap.size(); k++)
{
    cout << swap[k];
}
cout << endl;
```

}

**The function is written in a class**

The vector, art, has the user input. and for each element of the vector, it stores a line of string.
I want to access the string of the element and swap the letters of the string, which i believe would create a mirrored image.

I get compiling errors such as "cannot convert _normal iterator> to char" which i don't understand why because I am dealing with chars, the same type.
"no such operation as '='" ??

I am not understanding why. Can someone explain? Maybe my logic is wrong, so can someone help me rewrite it?

I want it to reflect/mirror it vertically.

Comment: Look what `begin()` and `end()` return.

Comment: Do you want to mirror it vertically or horizontally?

Comment: nitpick: [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) has two "i"s.

Comment: @maerics thats very irrelevant to the problem I'm having but thank you anyway..

Comment: anything to help a fellow coder =)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) to reverse each string in the `vector`.

```
void asci_art::display_backwards(vector<string> art)
{
  for( auto&& a : art ) {
    std::reverse(a.begin(), a.end()); // reverses each string
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Or if you want to reverse the order of the strings in the vector, a slightly different call to reverse will do the trick.

```
void asci_art::display_backwards(vector<string> art)
{
  std::reverse( art.begin(), art.end() );  // reverses order of strings in vector
  for( auto const& a : art ) {
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 Tell him explicitly that the first one is for vertical mirroring while the second is for horizontal mirroring. :D

Comment: @Praetorian it says it needs an initializer before ":"

Comment: @user2188311 Are you using a compiler that supports C++11's range-based for loop? If not, write a regular for loop `for( vector<string>::iterator first = art.begin(); first != art.end(); ++first ) { ... }`

Comment: @Praetorian im using a compiler in linux OS.

Comment: @user2188311 What compiler and version? If it's a newer version of gcc or clang, you may be able to get it to compile by adding the `-std=c++11` (or `-std=c++0x`) switch to the compiler options.

Comment: replace `for( auto const& a : art ) {` and the other one with `for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = art.begin(); it != art.end(); ++it) {`. Your compiler may not support c++11 syntax, but try the compiler switches of Praetorian first.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with : 
art[i].begin()+j=swap[j]
what are you trying to do? assigning 'swap[j]' which is a character to an integer?

Comment: i was hoping to store the character of art[i] into a char array, swap

Answer (score 0):

Within your code you are mixing the usage of direct array access and iterators.
To make your code work as wanted, you would need to decide for one of those.

A second thing is, you try to store the reversed array. Since you do not return the result of that, you would not need to do that. You can just directly output the data in reversed order.

Examples:

```
// using direct access
void asci_art::display_backwards_direct(std::vector<std::string> art) {
  std::cout << "Your Artwork in mirrored image" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "=============================" <<std::endl;

  for (signed int i = art.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    std::cout << art[i]; // depending on your data you might need endl here
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

// using iterators
void asci_art::display_backwards_iterators(std::vector<std::string> art) {
  std::cout << "Your Artwork in mirrored image" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "=============================" <<std::endl;

  for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = art.rbegin(); it != art.rend(); ++it) {
    std::cout << *it; // depending on your data you might need endl here
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

// using direct access
void asci_art::display_backwards_direct_horizontal(std::vector<std::string> art) {
  std::cout << "Your Artwork in mirrored image" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "=============================" <<std::endl;

  for (signed int i = 0; i < art.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << std::reverse(art[i].begin(), art[i].end()); // depending on your data you might need endl here
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

// using iterators
void asci_art::display_backwards_iterators_horizontal(std::vector<std::string> art) {
  std::cout << "Your Artwork in mirrored image" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "=============================" <<std::endl;

  for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = art.begin(); it != art.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << std::reverse(it->begin(), it->end()); // depending on your data you might need endl here
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

C++11 syntax would shorten the second version.

Unrelated: using references for passing arguments may speed up the application, when you deal with really vectors, so the vector would not be copied every time.

```
void some_function(std::vector<std::string> const & const_reference_to_my_string_vector) {
  std::cout << const_reference_to_my_string_vector.size() << std:endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it didn't output it mirrored

Comment: added the according versions for mirroring over a vertical axis.